# The requested URL /install/index was not found on this server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost, webmin

when trying to access my site glinks.tk I'm redirected to the configuration automatically, but when transferring my site to a VPS Wemin with Virtual Host I got problems, I put the files correctly but upon access I get the following message "The requested URL/install/index was not found on this server. " I've tried everything but I do not know how to solve it, the script I use is the Mighty URL Shortener and it uses two .htaccess one in the root and one in the webroot folder.

.htaccess from root:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

# No directory listings
IndexIgnore *

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Uncomment the following line if your webserver's URL is not directly related to physical file paths.
    # Also uncomment it if you are on 1&1 hosting
    #RewriteBase /

    # Comment the following line if you have not a .well-known directory in the root folder.
    RewriteRule ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1 [L]

    RewriteRule    ^$    /var/www/glinks/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) /var/www/glinks/webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php5_module>

</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

.htaccess from webroot:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the rules in the apache/site config files instead of .htaccess files? I remember something like this happening to me, and when I switched the rules to the `httpd.conf` file and `sites-enabled` folder's files it worked.

Comment: As an addition to my previous comment, this article also gives a lot of reasons why not to use htaccess files for trivial things like what you're trying to do: https://www.danielmorell.com/guides/htaccess-seo/basics/dont-use-htaccess-unless-you-must